# How to migrate multiple realm files in one App

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have two realm files in one App, something wrong when I wanna migrate them. I want realm update automatically when run in Xcode while does not change the **schemaVersion** every time.

```
class News: Object {
    @objc dynamic var name: String  
}

class NewsManager {
    static var realm = try! Realm()
    static var cacheRealm: Realm = {

        let documentDirectory = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask,
                                                         appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
        let url = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("cache.realm")
        var config = Realm.Configuration()
        config.fileURL = url
        return try! Realm(configuration: config)
    }()
}
```

When I add a new property to **News** such as **@objc dynamic var title: String**,
I add the following code in AppDelegate **func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool**

```
let config = Realm.Configuration(schemaVersion: 1, migrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in

    })
Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config
```

The message on crash at **return try! Realm(configuration: config)** in **NewsManager**.

```
Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Error Domain=io.realm Code=10 "Migration is required due to the following errors:
- Property 'News.test' has been added." UserInfo={Error Code=10, NSLocalizedDescription=Migration is required due to the following errors:
- Property 'News.test' has been added.}: file /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/swiftlang/swiftlang-900.0.69.2/src/swift/stdlib/public/core/ErrorType.swift, line 181
```

What should I do?

Realm: 3.0.1

Swift: 4.0

iOS  : 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realm is working as expected. Some types of model changes Realm can migrate automatically, others *require* you to provide a manual migration. The one in your example is one of them.

Since you added a new, non-optional property of type `String`, Realm needs to go through all your existing models and figure out what to put in that property. If the property were type `String?`, it would make sense to use `nil` as a default value, and Realm could carry out the migration automatically. However, since the type is `String` and there's no obvious sensible default, Realm requires you to manually specify a value for the new property for each model object.

The right way to fix this "problem" is to increment your schema number and provide a migration block that actually specifies the new values for new properties whenever you change your model in a way that requires a migration.

Please review our [documentation on migrations](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#migrations) for more details.

Comment: I add **@objc dynamic var title: String?** and **@objc dynamic var title: String = ""**, it also crash on **cache.realm**. So I have to increase the schemaVersion when run with Xcode after I add a new property?

Comment: You need to increase `schemaVersion` if you make a change that requires a migration block, such as adding a new non-optional property.

Answer (score 0):

Check it out https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#migrations. Realm site is very good for understanding how properly use Realm in your projects